# How to get rid of minus sign from signed zero

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I am using asin to calculate the angle. The code is as below :

```
double FindAngle(const double theValue)
{
     return asin(theValue);
}
```

FindAngle returns a -0.0 (signed zero), when the argument theValue = -0.0. Now, how do i get rid of the minus sign from the return value.

Comment: To be honest, I fail to see a reason for doing this. Asin will anyway return angle in -pi...pi.

Answer (score 11):

You can do the following:

```
double FindAngle(const double theValue)
{
     return (asin(theValue) + 0.0);
}
```

I had the same problem and that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to convert -0 to 0 and leave other untouched, just do a comparison.

```
double FindAngle(double value) {
    double res = asin(value);
    if (res == 0.0) res = 0.0;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I dont think comparing two doubles using "==" will always work

Comment: comparisons on floating point values should be done with some precision, i.e. fabs(a - b) < epsilon. Using '==' is plain wrong.

Comment: It works for this case. I believe the asker only wants to convert `-0.0` to `0.0`, not an range of floats in `[-epsilon, 0]`. There is only one `-0.0`, and the only values `== 0.0` are `-0.0` and `0.0`, so the `==` can be used.

Comment: @MadH: It is absolutely not "plain wrong".  In this case, any comparison using a threshold would be incorrect.

Comment: @yes, in this case threshold doesn't help; in order to solve a problem in place, one could divide by zero, then check which infinity it gives: +inf or -inf, and return fabs() in case of -inf

Comment: @ratnaveer, @MadH: There's absolutely *nothing* wrong with comparing floating-point values using `==` or `!=` assuming this is what is needed. In this particular case it is perfectly appropriate, under the formal interpretation of the problem (i.e. when we need to convert `-0` to `0`).

Answer (score 2):

include `<cmath>` and use the `abs` function on your return value, if you want all results to be positive, or check if your return value is equal to -0.0 and take the `abs` value of it, for just that case.

[abs function (c++ reference)](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/math/abs)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I realised my mistake. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method.

```
 value = Float.compare(value, -0.0f) == 0 ? 0.0f : value ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
double FindAngle(const double theValue)
{
    return abs(asin(value));
}
```

Comment: This will make all results positive, not just the negative zero.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that signed zero is your problem? (In this case, adding 0.0 to it—as proposed by [FacundoJ above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14015445/7275076)—would in fact solve it. Provided your arithmetic conforms to IEEE 754, that is.)

If, on the other hand, your problem is that `printf("%f", x)` produces `-0.000000` (or similar for a similar format specifier), then just adding 0.0 is not enough: you will get the same output for any small, but negative, value.

In this case some actual programming is needed (at least I know of no better solution). I used something like this the other day:

```
int snrfmt(char *s, const char *format, double x)
{
    int n, m;
    char z[32];

    n = sprintf(s, format, x);
    m = sprintf(z, format, -DBL_MIN);
    if (n == m && strcmp(s, z) == 0)
        n = sprintf(s, format, 0.0);
    return n;
}
```

as a kind-of replacement for `sprintf()`:

```
double x = -1.23E-45;
char nr[80];

(void)snrfmt(buf, "%#+010.4f", x);
puts(nr);
```

This produces "`+0000.0000`" as desired (but of course "`-0000.0001`" for `x = -0.50001E-4`).