# getting rid of signed zero

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm doing some matrix operations where the matrix elements obtains values from certain variables in the following way:

```
elem[1] = -x
```

but when `x = 0` it sets `-0` in the matrix which is undesirable. Any definitive way to prevent this?

Comment: What is the type of the matrix elements and why is -0 undesirable?

Comment: The type is likely `float` or `double` if that can happen at all ...

Comment: The matrix is float type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084970/how-to-get-rid-of-minus-sign-from-signed-zero?rq=1 suggests: `if (x == 0.) { x = 0.;}`

Comment: maybe std::fpclassify is of help for you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify

Comment: Signed zero is part of the IEEE 754 standard. There isn't much you can do about it. For most purposes (mainly arithmetic operations) it should make no difference. If it is important in your implementation just go over the matrix and set all zeros to +0;

Comment: *it sets -0 in the matrix which is undesirable* -- why do you deem this undesirable? +0.0 and -0.0 compare equal. To be pedantic, both +0.0 and -0.0 are a bit incorrect because zero is neither positive nor negative. The math still works with a sign, + or -, attached to zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
elem[i] = -x + 0.0;
```

I've tested the following code:

```
float a = -0.0; 
printf("%f %f\n", a, a + 0.0);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
-0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: This is awesome (branch-free!) if it's guaranteed to work by IEEE 754 -- but is it? As far as I know, _x_ +/-0.0 = _x_, so optimizing out the entire statement would be a valid compiler optimization in my opinion. Also, does this depend on rounding modes?

Comment: @Damon I'm not sure why does that happen. In fact is pretty weird to me the fact that `-0.0 + 0.0 == 0.0` and `-0.0 + -0.0 == -0.0` (at least in my gcc).

Comment: See https://kristerw.github.io/2021/10/19/fast-math/ ; it sure sounds like `x + 0.0` always gets the sign removed.